# How to create xml hierarchy from string path

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file with the structure like this

```
<Items>
   <Item ID="1">
      <Folder>Organisms\Pets\Cat</Folder>
   </Item>
   <Item ID="2">
      <Folder>Organisms\Pets\Horse</Folder>
   </Item>
   <Item ID="3">
      <Folder>Organisms\Pets\Fish</Folder>
   </Item>
   <Item ID="4">
      <Folder>Organisms\Pets\Dog</Folder>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

How do I create a hierarchy structure for the folders using xslt ?? So it will look like this:

```
<Folder>
 <Organisms>
   <Pets>
     <Dog/>
     <Cat/>
     <Horse/>
     <Fish/>
   </Pets>
 </Organisms>
</Folder>
```

Thanks for reading :)

-----------------Update-------------------------------------------

```
<xsl:template match="Item" name="split">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="Folder"/>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText)">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText,'\'),'\')"/>

                    <xsl:call-template name="split">

                        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '\')"/>

                    </xsl:call-template>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

I tried this and some how it works, but only problem is duplication. I don't know how to group the Organism as 1 node and Pets as another node

Comment: It can be done, but this isn't the kind of problem XSLT is optimized for. Frankly, I'd handle this one by hardcoding a small SAX or DOM application.

Comment: See the thing is my job requires me to achieve this using XSLT only :(

Comment: As I say, it can be done but it's going to be ugly. I'd suggest checking the [XSL FAQ website](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html) to see if you can adapt an existing solution.

Comment: I tested a solution, however I don't know how to remove the duplication. Please help me take a look

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: The result you posted is XML (with elements named `Folder`, `Organisms` and so on), yet in your XSLT you create `ul` and `li` elements. So please clarify whether you want to transform to XML with the structure you have posted or to some HTML nested list structure with `ul` and `li`.

Comment: I'd like to produce nested HTML list, I don't know how to explain it so just posted like that. My bad, sorry